# tensorflow c_api.h Why GPU is slower than CPU

Tags: c++, c, api, tensorflow

I have trained a `lstm mode` and I load the model in my C project to predict my data.I find the GPU is slowly than CPU.

Here is my configuration:

- gpu:nvidia TITAN X
- CUDA：9.0
- cudnn:7.0
- cpu: intel E5
- tensorflow: 1.11.0

I predicted about 200 data items and every data items calls the function ：

```
TF_SessionRun(sess,
nullptr, // Run options.
&input_op, &input_tensor, 1, // Input tensors, input tensor values, number of inputs.
&out_op, &output_tensor, 1, // Output tensors, output tensor values, number of outputs.
nullptr, 0, // Target operations, number of targets.
nullptr, // Run metadata.
status // Output status.
);
```

Every time GPU is slower than the CPU.

Is my method wrong ?

Is there a way to increase the speed?

Can I enter data in batches for prediction and if so how?

This is the c_api.h [enter link description here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api.h)

Comment: I had no idea there was tensorflow for C, i always thought it was a python library.  This doesnt help in answering your question but thanks for asking it :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an overhead to transfer data to the GPUs memory , you see this trend sometimes even in Python for extremely small datasets , where the CPU sometimes outperforms the GPU as most of time the gpu isn't utilized but rather is waiting for the next batch of data to come in , with a dataset size of 200 this seems like the most plausible reason .

As for making it faster it faster the Python api had an option in batch mode to preload the data into the gpu which somewhat offsets this issue , check for a similar option in the c api